# The distance of a point to a subset is greater than the distance of the subset to the boundary of the big set

Tags: general-topology

Hi I'm trying to prove this that seems very obvious but I can't seem to prove it: if $V$ and $U$ are open sets (in $\mathbb{R^n}$) and $\overline{V} \subseteq U$ and $z \notin U$ then $d(\overline{V};\partial U) \leq d(\overline{V};z)$

Comment: ah yes sorry, obviously. $z \notin U$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since singleton $\{z\}$ is compact and $\overline V$ is closed, there is $v\in\overline V$ with $d(z,\overline V)=d(z,v)$. Then $v\in U$. Let $S$ be the straight line segment connecting $z$ and $v$. Let $r=\inf\{d(z,s):s\in S\cap U\}$. Then $0\le r<d(z,v)$. Let $t$ be the point on $S$ distance $r$ from $z$. It is easily verified that $t\in Bd(U)$ and  hence $d(z,Bd(U))\le d(z,t)<d(z,v)$, which is correct  but not exactly what you wanted so let me do it right. We have $d(Bd(U),\overline V)\le d(t,v)\le d(z,v)$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Really thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for the question!